# Umbraco8: Upload images directly to azure blob storage

Tags: azure, content-management-system, umbraco, umbraco8

I am using Umbraco 8. I want to to upload images directly to azure blob while creating content. Do I need to create a custom file upload control in umbraco for this or are there any plugins available for that?
The solutions that are already available expect either the images to be already present in blob or expect the user to create content first and then migrate those images to cloud as a part if deployment.

PS: I am new to Umbraco and want to host Umbraco instance on my VM instead of voting for Umbraco cloud.

Answer (score 1):

There's a package for that here: https://our.umbraco.com/packages/collaboration/umbracofilesystemprovidersazure/

And there's even a tutorial here on how to do it yourself if you like: https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Extending/FileSystemProviders/Azure-Blob-Storage/